# Suppress HtmlUnit Apache logging

Tags: java, apache, htmlunit

I want to suppress certain logs of Apache's HttpClient when using HtmlUnit. I'm using HtmlUnit 2.27 with JDK logging. Everytime I explicitly set the level of 'org.apache.http.wire' to Off, HtmlUnit resets the level to null.

For example:

```
//turn on all logging
for(java.util.logging.Handler item : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
    item.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.ALL);
}
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINE);

//suppress apache logs
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF); 

//CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

(new WebClient()).getPage("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt");
System.out.println("org.apache.http.wire=" + java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").getLevel());
```

This returns:

```
org.apache.http.wire=null
```

If I use Apache HttpClient directly or reference Apache HttpClient before HtmlUnit (i.e. uncomment the CloseableHttpClient line), then the logging is suppressed and output returns:

```
org.apache.http.wire=OFF
```

Any ideas on how to suppress "org.apache.http.wire" logs without my hack of referencing CloseableHttpClient before HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix: don't use java.util.logging. Once I switch commons logging to use log4j, everything worked as expected. I assume it's a bug with java.util.logging and HtmlUnit...